# Navigating back when save fails in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When something goes wrong in a save I do the following right now but it feels a bit wrong.

```
  if @store.update_attributes(params[:store])
    redirect_to admin_stores_path, notice: "Updated ..."
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Error"
    render action: 'edit'
  end
```

Would it be better to use the browsers navigate back functionality and redirect_back or something? I can't even remember where I copied the above from but it does produce some odd results at times.

Could someone tell me the best way to handle a failed save; navigation wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why a `render` is used instead of a `redirect` is simple:

- You keep the object variables so the user doesn't have to retype everything if he made a mistake.
- the errors are stored inside the object itself so you need it to display them

Comment: Then I am not doing anything wrong in other words. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you write controller actions you handles 2 situations: success and failure. If error occures you will **render** the same action to show validation errors and if action is successful you will **redirect_to** somewere. This is common practice and you even can find such 'patterns' in differrent books about Rails.
About redirect_to :back, I prefer not to use it, because it can deliver a lot of troubles :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the most used way to handle form submission in rails. When the object got saved you want user to redirect other page, mostly show page.

The most important is render action, when you say render action you actually want to render view of that action. the view have form_for and error_message_for, these render form with prepoulate input values and object errors which occurs while saving it.